# Comunication between two Node.js express requests

Tags: node.js, express, signals, wait

I have two clients. A client sends an HTTP request to node.js express server and this writes in the DB then waits that value changes. It changes when the other client sends an HTTP request to node.js express and it UPDATE the record in the DB. Then the first request sends a response JSON to the first client.

The idea is that the first client process waits a signal from the second client process without using busy wait (like reads from deatabase every 100ms). Here the code (uniqueid is a value that is PRIMARY KEY of that table's row):

```
var foo = function(uniqueid, client, cb){
  var query="UPDATE... WHERE uniqueid=" + db.escape(uniqueid) + ";";
  db.query(query, function(err, result, fields){

    if(client==1){ //if we are client1 we wait

      waitClient2(uniqueid, function(callback){                            
        //Then read the new value
        getValue(uniqueid, function(v){
          cb(v);
        });    
      });

    }else{ //else unlock client1

      unlockClient1(uniqueid);                        
      //Then read the new value
      getValue(uniqueid, function(v){
        cb(v);
      });
    }

  });
}

var waitClient2 = function(uniqueid, cb){
  //wait(uniqueid)
  //cb(0) for unlock foo
}

var unlockClient1 = function(uniqueid){
  //signal(uniqueid)
}
```

Is there a way to send a message (signal) from a client request to another client request so the second can unlocks itself editing two latest functions?
I appreciate other ideas too.
Thank you.